# Allowing another user to start/stop/configure Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an VM in Azure, and I'd like a colleague to manage it as well.

I've added him as

1. a Global Administrator in Azure Active Directory.
2. Coadministrator for my account

However, the VM does not show up when he logs in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You setup the user as an admin on the WAAD directory, but that doesn't have any relation to your subscription or VMs.  Instead you should add that user as a co-admin to your Subscription via the management portal using the Settings option in the left-hand navigation pane.  Instructions can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456328.aspx.