# Share VM management in Azure with another user

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine

I have seen this question [Allowing another user to start/stop/configure Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448392/allowing-another-user-to-start-stop-configure-azure-vm) but the link in accepted answer is no longer valid.

A customer is requesting us to use Azure for hosting a Linux VM but we should maintain the server. Besides having access to the VM itself though the OS (ssh, https or what ever), is it possible to have the customer give us administration rights only for that VM within Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  They simply add you as a user in their Azure Subscription and grant Contribute access to the VM.  This won’t give you management access to the disks/NICs etc. associated with the VM.  To do that, you need contribute access to those (easily done if they’re by themselves in a Resource Group).